# SignalR communication between different version

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Is it possible to manage the client app (.net 4.0 and aspnet.signalr) to communicate properly with the server (wep api, .net core 2.1 with aspnetcore.signalr)?

Every attempt to start connection from the client side ends up with *Bad Request* exception.
When I use the client written in .net core 2.1 everything is ok.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the non-Core client with a Core server? They're different. Use the Core client, which is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

Comment: You can't, ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR are not compatible https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences